# Does Sell Call/Sell Put affect a share price

Tags: options, bid-ask

I am using a option flow provider that cost about $99 a month. Its filter by default only trigger on "Ask/Above Ask" for call & put , but Bid/Below Bid (namely sell call/sell put) is not triggered on.

I am trying to analyse if a Sell Call/Sell Put will affect the share price movement (From the Bid Side) or only a Buy Call/Buy Put will affect the share price movement.

Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you sell an option, there's no direct effect on share price from that action.

However, if a market maker or a trader in size buys those options, they become more long or more short delta. If the underlying's price then moves, their delta may increase or decrease so in response, they might buy or short the underlying.